# How to create listing screen with image in android

Tags: android

I'm working on android mobile app.(I'm new to this field )[image]

I'm having trouble in creating listing screen with image, (as in image) any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Below is my code

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="8dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Comment: whats your problem?? and what you have done so far??

Comment: what you have done to do this. and what is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a lot going on so I recommend you to check this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html